# Replace all mentions in message discord api

Tags: javascript, html, discord

I am using discord api get and post requests to get messages from a channel but I don’t know how to convert the mentions in the message from <@....> to @hello.

I have seen that in discord js there is a function called .cleanContent() but I was wondering how to make it in JavaScript.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with [ask] - as it currently stands, it's really not clear what you're trying to do, or how *exactly* [tag:html] & [tag:javascript] have *anything* to do with it.

Comment: I am trying to make discord’s cleanContent function in JavaScript and I put html so we know it’s not node js

Comment: Discord.js is a library that's written in JavaScript already and released "open source" (meaning you can view and inspect their source code). Why would you need to "*make*" the "*cleanContent function in JavaScript*" yourself if it's [freely available](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/213acd799738b888d550cdf3f08906764f8288e0/packages/discord.js/src/util/Util.js#L528)? Take its definition and adjust it as necessary for use in your own project.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what i needed!